# Windows form thick client application - multiple versions installed on the same machine

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, windows-installer, thick-client

We have an old Windows Form thick client application It is an internal tool. It gets installed on everyone's desktop as a windows application. There is a sudden frantic need for creating a separate installer for a client specific version of the same internal tool. Some of the people will need access to both versions of the exact same application. 
My question is how do I create two installers of the same application and get it to show up in the start up as well as a icon on the desktop.
I know that if I change the Product code on the setup properties, both the versions get installed side by side. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 1):

In the installer, simply use a different product id and upgrade code.  How you specifically do that depends on what type of installer you have.

Comment: agreed. If you are using anything that is MS Setup-based, you might also want to investigate the use of transforms (to change the codes). This will allow you to build a single msi rather than two.